# Voice leading options for 12 bar blues

Tags: blues, voice-leading

Here is a rootless voicing, 12 bar blues from Jerr Coker, Jazz Keyboard...

[image]

...it presents the typical A/B voicings. In this case 7/3/13 and 3/7/9. In a roots by descending fifth progress the A and B voicings just alternate to create smooth voice leading.

My question is about the areas in the orange boxes that aren't progression by descending fifth.

In the first box the progression is descending fourth and he just reverses the desc. 5th pattern.

In the second the chord is repeated with no change in voicing/inversion.

In the third the chord type is repeated with a parallel movement.

In each of these three areas are there voice leading alternatives? Alternatives that keep to the style of the examples.

Comment: Are you looking to preserve the A/B voicings, or are you just looking to preserve the overall feel, even if the new voicings introduce or exclude particular chord tones/extensions?

Comment: I think both. I didn't say it explicitly but my "problem" was about two changes in the same direction. It seems to do that you _must_ use another voicing. Style-wise, that seems fine as long as the chord at least contains the tritone, then you can add other tones freely, 9th and 13th like in the examples, or roots and 5ths to get other voice leading options, with the caveat to keep altered 9th/5ths on just `V`.

Comment: Let me see if I've got it. For example, the motion from m. 1 to m. 2 is downward, but then the boxed pair shifts back upward. You'd like another downward motion that, ideally, preserves the specific voicing or, failing that, preserves the overall style.

Comment: Right. Another example could be bass `D C G` the RH could be `3-7-#9 | 7-1-3 | 7-3-6`, so the `C` chord is the 'other' voicing to get a different line on top, instead of the same back and forth from the same positions. There could be other combinations. The point is just an approach to start moving beyond playing the Coker examples _literally_, but keeping in the same style.

Comment: IMO, you should self-answer this one. I think your insights are valuable, and although I've been considering an answer of my own, I don't see it varying much from what you've already discovered.

Comment: OK, I was just hoping to hear from someone with real jazz experience, I'm just teaching myself at home.

Comment: Well, I have real jazz experience, on piano in particular, so I'm happy to write an answer if you feel it would be valuable; otherwise, I'll happily upvote yours. Just ping me if you'd prefer not to self-answer.